# What happened to ifilter?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, built-in

In comparing documentation for itertools between Python [2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) and [3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html), I noticed `ifilter`, `imap`, `izip` are missing from Python 3.  I suspect this is because many builtin keywords have been converted to generators and replaced former keywords, but it is unclear in this case.

Is it true `ifilter`, `imap`, `izip` are now equivalent to `filter`, `map`, `zip` in Python 3?  If not, where can I find rationales for why certain methods were removed from current `itertools`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Python 2.3 introduced the `itertools` module, which defined variants of the global `zip()`, `map()`, and `filter()` functions that returned iterators instead of lists. In Python 3, those global functions return iterators, so those functions in the itertools module have been eliminated.

[image]

- Instead of `itertools.izip()`, just use the global `zip()` function.
- Instead of `itertools.imap()`, just use `map()`.
- `itertools.ifilter()` becomes `filter()`.
- The itertools module still exists in Python 3, it just doesn’t have the functions that have migrated to the global namespace. The 2to3 script is smart enough to remove the specific imports that no longer exist, while leaving other imports intact.

Read more [here](http://www.cmi.ac.in/~madhavan/courses/prog2-2012/docs/diveintopython3/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html)

Comment: Nice reference.  Thanks!